# Can I limit the number of rows read by avro-tools?

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I am using `avro-tools tojson file.avro` to inspect a large Avro file. I am only interested in seeing a few examples, just to get a feeling for the data.

Is there an option for `avro-tools tojson` that limits the number of rows read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option for avro-tools tojson that limits the number of rows read:

```
avro-tools tojson --head=<n> <filename>
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? I keep getting "head is an unrecognized option" issue

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not possible. See source code [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/BinaryFragmentToJsonTool.java).
But it should be easy enough to just add a limit to the code.
Or just use `head` to fake it

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can add it to avro-tools.

Comment: This is actually possible @LuckyGuess, the actual class used is `DataFileReadTool` and one can specify `head` :) https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileReadTool.java#L58.

Comment: TIL. Thanks for replying back.